# Populate Neo4j with spark connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j

I'm using Spark2 with Neo4j 3 (installed on one node) with this Spark/Neo4J https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector

I can auth with  to my database.

In every documentations that I read, no one is populate Neo4j directly with Spark.

They load data into Neo4J with directly request in UI or other way.

I have to ingest data in Neo4j with spark.

Do I have to map to each Dataframe and create query and execute them ?

Sources :
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/neo4j.html : Only request...

https://neo4j.com/developer/apache-spark/ :
org.neo4j.spark.Neo4j(sc).cypher(query,[params]),nodes(query,[params]),rels(query,[params]).

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of the neo4j-spark-connector, you should be able to load in data from your DataFrame into Neo4j database using the `mergeEdgeList()` function. This [thread](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/issues/27) discusses the same matter, and may be helpful to you.